# Assign a value to filters in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

My JSON data are like: records.json

```
[
  {
  "id":"1",
  "name":"Report1",
    "category":"A"
    },

  {
  "id":"2",
  "name":"Report2",
    "category":"A"
    },
  {
  "id":"3",
  "name":"Report3",
    "category":"B"
    },
  {
  "id":"4",
  "name":"Report4",
    "category":"C"
    }
 ]
```

and HTML page is like :

```
<input ng-model="query" />
<li ng-repeat="record in records | filter:query" />
```

This code gives the list of records according to query, but i want only those records which having only category A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explain by the [AngularJS documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3afilter), you can simply do something like that :

```
<li ng-repeat="record in records | filter: {category:'A', name:query}">
    <!-- ... -->
</li>
```

Notice that if your filter becomes to heavy, it is probably a best idea to [make your own filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.templates.filters.creating_filters).